# Facing Problem of Getting late Email by using Phpmailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using a `PHP` mailer for sending an email, but email is getting 4 to 5 minutes to reach the client's inbox. This issue is been facing only on Gmail. When I send emails to any other platform like outlook and yahoo etc, there, the email will get within the second.

Can you please help me out with this issue? Please tell me the reason or solution??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the SO tour, read about how to ask good questions, as well as this question checklist. Lastly please learn how to create a minimal reproducible example to show us, with emphasis on the minimal part

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are expecting SMTP delivery to be quick. SMTP offers no such guarantees. That you are seeing quick deliveries sometimes is down to luck. There are many other factors that may affect delivery time, such as greylisting, sending history, volume, and reputation, message content and size, time of day, etc. You may find there is interesting info in your mail server logs that may help you improve things, but again, there are no guarantees that you can do anything at all.